# Directory.GetFiles() causes blue screen of death

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I was searching for a test project I had coded a few months ago, and could not remember in which solution I had placed it.  I decided to write some quick code to get all my Visual Studio 2010 projects' c-sharp source files, and look through them for a literal I know should exist in the file.

I started in debug mode, and when my code executed this statement, I got a blue screen of death:

```
            string[] results = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\<user name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\", "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

After a reboot, I checked the event logs, and I only saw the generic unexpected shut-down messages.  I brought up the temp project, ran in debug mode again, and got the BSOD again.  If I remove the SearchOption.AllDirectories param, the code doesn't break, but it doesn't get me the results I want either.  But when I put it back, BSOD again.

Does anyone have any insight as to what could be causing this, or where I might be able to look (logs, etc) to see what the issue is?  I did not see a kernel dump in the Windows directory, and the event log doesn't show anything that would stand out to me.  FYI, I can run the same search from Windows Explorer with no errors and all the files returned.

*** Update ***
I ran the same snippet of code but changed the file mask to *.txt, and it runs with no issue, so the .cs extension is playing into the error for some reason.  Could it be having an issue listing the .cs file that I am running in debug?

Comment: just use built-in windows search, would save you time

Comment: Perhaps a hardware error in the disk or the disk controller which only manifests when certain parts of the disk are accessed?

Comment: You state you have ran the search successfully already in windows explorer... doesn't this solve the purpose you created this project for?

Comment: Blue screens from managed code were discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/q/277959/397817 and the consensus was that only kernel level failures can cause it. I concur with Matthew that it's more likely a system/disk failure than a problem with your code.

Comment: athabaska, I could do that, but I actually wanted to search for various terms, etc.  It seemed easier at the time to just write some quick and dirty code in a test project I already had up at the time.  After the error occurred, I'm curious as to what would cause it.

Answer (score -2):

I guess there is a disk hardware error in one of your projects. Try enumerating all files there recursively and log it to see which one causes BSOD.

Comment: This is just plagiarism of Matthew Watson's comment.

Comment: @Sayse But he didn't provide a possible solution.

Comment: I would argue you haven't either since your "possible solution" is purely guesswork which would indicate that more information would be required from the OP to give a valid answer.

Comment: @Sayse But then one could argue there is no better solution, as disk problems fall out of this site's purpose.